# How to count number of values in a row and store total count to array

Tags: shell, awk, text-processing

I have a scenario where i want to get count of all values row by row and store it to dynamic array

**Data in file :**

```
"A","B","C","B"
"P","W","R","S"
"E","U","C","S"
"Y","F","C"
```

**first row as  :** 4 -> values

**second row as :** 4 -> values

**third row as  :** 4 -> values

**fourth row as :** 3 -> values

**Expected Output :**
**store to array :** array_list=(4,4,4,3)

written a script but not working

```
array_list=()

while read -r line 
do 
    var_comma_count=`echo "$line" | tr -cd , | wc -c`
    array_list=+($( var_comma_count))
done < demo.txt
```

**when i print array it should give me all values :**  `echo "{array_list[@]}"`

**Note :**
The file might contain empty lines at last which should not be read

when i count file it gave me count : 5 , it should have ignored last line which is empty

where as when i use awk it give me proper count : `awk '{print NF}' demo.txt -> 4`

I know processing file using while loop is not a best practise , but any better solution will be appreciated

Comment: `array_list=($(awk '{print NF}' demo.txt))`? `store it to dynamic array` it's just an "array", it's not called "dynamic" I mean.

Comment: Can your quoted fields contains commas or newlines?

Comment: Also, you've been told before that you should copy/paste your scripts into http://shellcheck.net before asking questions about them, please do that and then edit your question to replace your current script with the fixed result.

Comment: @EdMorton Sure next time will check code with shell check and post question

Comment: No need to wait for next time, you can do it right now this time, it'll take you about 2 minutes at most.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that reading those values into a shell array is a good starting point for whatever else you want to do as it suggests you plan to do further text manipulation in shell rather than just doing whatever else you plan to do in the awk script.

Comment: The answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858165/how-to-count-number-of-values-in-a-row-and-store-total-count-to-array#comment119942052_67858165) is extremely important, by the way, and has a huge impact on possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this might be easier using awk, set the FS to a comma and check if the number of fields is larger than 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

array_list=($(awk -v FS=, 'NF>0 {print NF}' demo.txt))
echo "${array_list[@]}"
```

Output

```
4 4 4 3
```

The awk command explained:

```
awk -v FS=, '    # Start awk, set the Field Separator (FS) to a comma
NF>0 {print NF}  # If the Number of Fields (NF) is greater than 0, print the NF
' demo.txt       # Close awk and set demo.txt as the input file
```

---

Another option could be first matching the format of the whole line. If it matches, there is at least a single occurrence.

Then split the line on a comma.

```
array_list=($(awk '/^"[A-Z]"(,"[A-Z]")*$/{print(split($0,a,","));}' demo.txt))
echo "${array_list[@]}"
```

Output

```
4 4 4 3
```

The awk command explained:

```
awk '/^"[A-Z]"(,"[A-Z]")*$/{   # Regex pattern for the whole line, match a single char A-Z between " and optionally repeat preceded by a comma
  print(split($0,a,","));      # Split the whole line `$0` on a comma and print the number of parts
}
' demo.txt
```

Comment: can you explain the code in detail will be helpful for others too

Comment: is it possible to use this `@` instead of '*'  in `array_list [ * ]`

Comment: @codeholic24 Yes, I have updated the answer.